# "Absolute paths not recommended in JSPs" ? - Is this also apply to the @RequestMapping()?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, intellij-idea, absolute-path

I got warnings from IntelliJ that "Absolute paths not recommended in JSPs"

I understand that, for internal files locations, like "styles.css or script.js", we should use relative path, something like this -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/css/styles.css">
```

But how about the @RequestMapping(), @GetMapping, @PostMapping, ... , and etc

For example, I have a form here:

```
<form method="post" action="/file/upload-submitted" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
...
</form>
```

and I also have:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/file/upload-submitted")
```

IntelliJ also give me warning "Absolute paths not recommended in JSPs" at "/file/upload"
Is it the correct warning?

***The reason that I put the absolute path there because there are multiple paths to get to the form.

```
@GetMapping(value = {"/file", "/file/upload"})
```

Comment: You are mixing club soda with single malt. Thats a no-no. Absolute path in your jsp are are for static resources. While for  @PostMapping() etc you are mapping dynamic variables. I dont see an issue here what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry, I am new and a little bit confused here. In the form, If I do this, action="upload-submitted" , the IntelliJ won't give me the warning (but sometimes, my website can't find the page). But If I do this, action="/file/upload-submitted" , the IntelliJ gives me the warning (but my website always find the page).

Comment: What is your question now? Is it like in the headline if absolute or relative urls are recommended? Or is it why your "website can't find the page"? For a reader and possible author of answers it would be helpful if you have concrete questions that are easy to identify. Thank you.